# MacOS, CLion, CMake, OpenCV simple usage to display image from file

Tags: c, opencv

I try to use on Mac OS X OpenCV library

I have installed it with homebrew using this code:

```
$ brew tap homebrew/science 
$ brew install opencv
$ brew install opencv3
```

Than in CLion -> CMakeList.txt added following:

```
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED core imgproc highgui) 
set(OpenCV_LIBS opencv_core opencv_imgproc opencv_highgui) 
target_link_libraries(my_project_name ${OpenCV_LIBS})
```

And the code to test loading and displaying image using OpenCV looks like this:

```
#include <cv.h>
#include <highgui.h>
#include "test_opencv.h"

static void test_display_image(void) {
    IplImage *image;
    image= cvLoadImage("./test/resources/RGBA_8bits.png", 1);
    cvNamedWindow("OpenCV Image Loading", 1);
    cvShowImage("OpenCV Image Loading", image);
}
```

Comment: Btw, *don't* use obsolete C api!

Comment: What you mean by obsolete C api? is there new version of C api?  I downloaded I think the newest OpenCV version. I am programming in C not C++.

Comment: C api is obsolete, and still available just as legacy. New projects shouldn't use it

Comment: Also, your question is _not_ a question, and your answer is _not_ an answer. You should split your question in two, one actual question and one actual answer. Or even better, this should be in the Documentation

Comment: Yeah but I have adding quastion and just later found that the error was not in this code but somewhere else and just remove question. But what api i can use with C ? I want C api as I am programming in C. I have to make some bridging with C++ api? or what?

Comment: I cannot answer that. I'm just warning you that using obsolete api may be a bad idea

Comment: Yeah but I just want to use from this openCV some image processing apis like image resizing/rotating If I can I don't want to mix C with C++

Answer (score 5):

When installing with **homebrew** `opencv3` is installed `keg-only` so the symlinks are not created automatically.

You have to run following command to crate the symlinks:

```
$ brew ln opencv3 --force
```

See [this](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-science/issues/2466) GitHub issue.

Your `CMakeLists.txt` should look like this:

```
project(test)

find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_executable(test_cv main.cpp) 

# linking
target_link_libraries(test_cv ${OpenCV_LIBS})
```